# Less CSS variable for keyname change?

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm new to `LESS CSS`.

In my mide `LESS CSS` Code. Just example.

```
@block : body;
@name  : color;
@value : #99CC00;

@block
{
    @name : @value
}
```

I want this output

```
body
{
    color : #99CC00
}
```

Is it posible or not ? If posible please give me the `LESS CSS` code.

This is my problem

```
.browser-fix(@key,@value)
{
    -webkit-@key: @value;
    -moz-@key: @value;
    -ms-@key: @value;
    -o-@key: @value;
    @key: @value;
}

p
{
    .browser-fix(box-shadow,1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset);
    .browser-fix(transform,rotate(30deg));
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: for prefix `-webkit-@name` , `-moz-@name` , `-ms-@name`

Comment: What you want to do doesn't seem to make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that using a variable to define left-hand side of an assignment is not possible in LESS.

But you could use a [parametric mixin](http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins) and a selector interpolation to accomplish at least half what you are trying to do.

```
@block: body;

.color-mixin(@value) {
    color: @value;
}

@{block} {
    .color-mixin(#99CC00);
}
```

**Edit:**

To address your problem, I would personally do separate mixins for each browser specific attribute because browser specific attributes do not always match the pattern you specified e.g. setting opacity. Separate mixins are also easier to read.

```
.box-shadow(@shadow) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
    -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
    box-shadow: @shadow;
}

.rotate(@degrees) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(@degrees);
    -moz-transform: rotate(@degrees);
    -ms-transform: rotate(@degrees);
    -o-transform: rotate(@degrees);
    transform: rotate(@degrees);
}

// Example of an attribute that does not match the pattern.
.opacity(@opacity) {
    opacity: @opacity / 100;
    filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity})";
}

p {
    .box-shadow(1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset);
    .rotate(30deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use this simple Less CSS mixin**

```
.vender-fix(@name; @value) {
  -webkit-@{name}: @value;
  -moz-@{name}: @value;
  -ms-@{name}: @value;
  -o-@{name}: @value;
  @{name}: @value;
}

.example {
  .vender-fix(transition, width 300ms);
}
```

**Output:**

```
.example {
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms;
  -ms-transition: width 300ms;
  -o-transition: width 300ms;
  transition: width 300ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about mixins http://lesscss.org/#-mixins in less for prefixing then you can do like this:

```
.border-radius (@radius) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since Version: 1.6.0 LESS allows css property name be a variable.

http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties